# 'npm start' kicks off loop to install expo-cli

Tags: react-native, npm

**QUESTION:** How can I make it so `$ echo $PATH` returns `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

**BACKSTORY:**

1. I did an `npm install` on terminal (macOS Catalina) and started
   to get into a loop about installing expo cli when trying to `npm
   start`. I've since followed instructions here:
   https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

   - had to execute step 5 (from link above) as `source ~/.bash_profile`
     Tried `npm start` but still running into the loop
2. Already have npm 6.13.4 installed. However, running npm start results in below. Notice how it says **Expo CLI installed** but asked to install globally again so the 2nd time I say n:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:rn-starter user$ npm start

> @ start /Users/user/Desktop/REACT NATIVE/rn-starter
> expo start

This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? Y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
Expo CLI installed. You can run `expo --help` for instructions.
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? n
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-04-03T14_39_24_884Z-debug.log
```

3. Here's what's on line 8 of the log file:

`8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Desktop/REACT NATIVE/rn-starter/node_modules/.bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

4. I've previously installed Anaconda (several months back) and have uninstalled it using https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ However, running `$ echo $PATH` results in 
   `/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

**QUESTION:** How can I make it so `$ echo $PATH` returns `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

Appreciate any suggestions that can help!

Answer (score 0):

How is your `package.json` file?
Your npm start must is calling the expo

Comment: Yes, that file does reference expo --- "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start"..}

Comment: Have you installed the expo globally?

Does the expo -h command return something?

Comment: Expo not installed correctly

`npm install -g expo-cli` 
run this command again in bash (if you already have it) in the machine's root directory

Comment: then run `expo -V`, which should show the installed expo version